Vue executing method at @click does not work
I have a Vue application with a navbar and some items:
<div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-start">
                <a @click="test" class="navbar-item">
                    Home
                </a>

                <a @click="test" class="navbar-item">
                    Shopping
                </a>
            </div>
</div>

The test method looks like this:
const test = () => {
    console.log("testt")
}

When I click one of the  tags nothing happens in my browser console. I am using typescript as script language inside the Vue file and composition api. I also tried @click="asdf()" but then I get the output that test is no function. Does somebody know which mistake I am making?
Here is the complete file:
<template>
    <nav class="navbar is-primary" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
            <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
                    <path d="M 12 4 C 9.8026661 4 8 5.8026661 8 8 C 5.8026661 8 4 9.8026661 4 12 L 4 24 C 4 26.197334 5.8026661 28 8 28 L 20 28 C 22.197334 28 24 26.197334 24 24 C 26.197334 24 28 22.197334 28 20 L 28 8 C 28 5.8026661 26.197334 4 24 4 L 12 4 z M 12 6 L 24 6 C 25.116666 6 26 6.8833339 26 8 L 26 20 C 26 21.116666 25.116666 22 24 22 L 11 22 C 10.43497 22 10 21.56503 10 21 L 10 14 L 12 14 L 12 18 C 12 19.093063 12.906937 20 14 20 L 18 20 L 20 20 L 22 20 C 23.093063 20 24 19.093063 24 18 L 24 11 C 24 9.3550302 22.64497 8 21 8 L 10 8 C 10 6.8833339 10.883334 6 12 6 z M 8 10 L 21 10 C 21.56503 10 22 10.43497 22 11 L 22 18 L 20 18 L 20 14 C 20 12.906937 19.093063 12 18 12 L 14 12 L 12 12 L 10 12 C 8.9069372 12 8 12.906937 8 14 L 8 21 C 8 22.64497 9.3550302 24 11 24 L 22 24 C 22 25.116666 21.116666 26 20 26 L 8 26 C 6.8833339 26 6 25.116666 6 24 L 6 12 C 6 10.883334 6.8833339 10 8 10 z M 14 14 L 18 14 L 18 18 L 14 18 L 14 14 z"></path>
                </svg>
            </a>

            <a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false"
                data-target="navbarBasicExample">
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
            <div class="navbar-start">
                <a @click="test" class="navbar-item">
                    Home
                </a>

                <a @click="asdf" class="navbar-item">
                    Shopping
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

const router = useRouter();

const test = () => {
    console.log("testt")
}

</script>


It should work just fine, this is the code in a vue playground

as stated, the code works, at least in isolation.  post enough code that the issue is reproducible.

I added the complete file at the bottom @yoduh

<script lang="ts"> is not valid composition API. You're missing the keyword "setup".  It should be <script setup lang="ts">

Composition api isn't restricted to "script setup". But if you use this syntax then use the correct tag

Perfect, thank you so much for your comment. Now it works :) @yoduh

I forgot to add setup to the script tag. Now it works
